# Product description/name truncated in Prestashop back-office

Tags: php, prestashop, maxlength

I'm having a little trouble on one of my Presta website.
When I go to the Active Carte section, and display details of one active cart, the name of the product is truncated, the max is not always the same but is around 500 characters.

See :

`Placard Kazed
Placard sur mesure : FAÇADE - COULISSANT - Coulissant KARACTER 3 DAMIER, 3 vantaux (larg. 800mm) Dimensions de la façade : H: 2400 X L: 2400mm Profil DEDICACE Wengé cannelé , avec sur-poignée Poignée: Sur poignée DEDICACE Effet inox brossé Vantail 1 avec 4 zones (567.00€ + 1.75€ Eco-participation)Décor A: Alu brosséDécor B: Blanc mat Vantail 2 avec 4 zones (567.00€ + 1.75€ Eco-participation)Décor A: Alu brosséDécor B: Blanc mat Vantail 3 avec 4 zones (567.00€ + 1.75€ Eco-participation)Décor A: Alu brosséDécor B: Bla`

There should be something like `Blanc, Prix : 1700€` after `Bla` ..

It's also truncated in the front office when you are in the cart section.

Anyone can help ?

I already saw AdminProducts, AdminCarts, Product, but did not found nothing.And i changed the fields_product_comment.text & .content from  VARCHAR to TEXT.

Thanks !

Comment: What do you call the "Active Carte section"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know that the module generated a new product each time since it's a custimized product it's pretty logic .. Anyway.

I just had to change the type of the field `value` in NAME_custimized_data from VARCHAR(500) to TEXT !